# joda-time 1.6.2 jar not downloading from maven central repository

Tags: java, maven-2, jodatime, repository

I am an issue where I'm trying to bring in the joda-time jar but Eclipse can't find it, for some reason. This is the message I get: `1/25/11 11:53:22 AM CST: Missing artifact joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6.2:compile`

Here is my dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
   <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

However, I can go to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/1.6.2/ and it's definitely there.

Any ideas on why it seems I'm unable to retrieve it? If there's any other information that might seem pertinent, let me know and I'll include it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've sometimes run into this with other artifacts when the .m2 repo gets munged.  Delete the .m2/joda-time folder and try again.  If that doesn't work show us your repository list.  I think if you generate an effective pom, it will show the complete list.  If it doesn't, show your repositories section from settings.xml, parent pom, and poms.

Also what version of maven are you using?

Finally, if I run into tricky maven issues I generally try to solve it at the command line using maven (preferably same version m2eclipse is using) and resolve it there, when done, resolve it in m2.